# Home server with different OS's instead of multiple PC?

Tags: home-networking, power-management, home-server, cluster

I'm just thinking about that instead of buying powerful notebooks and PC-s for my family members is that possible to create just one powerful PC, with the different OS preinstalled on it, and just stream the programs and even the whole OS to small client netbooks or mini PC's? And use just one really high-end GPU for gaming, video editing, programming etc. Even if I'm not thinking about using parallel for different users, this will be much easier and cheaper than buying a gaming PC for the kid, one other for work, another lightweight for the wife, and a pure Linux one just for banking, and another one for bringing it to holidays etc. Is that possible, even on the local network if it will lag on external connections?

If this is possible what should I use for it, how can I stream programs or even OS's?

Comment: What you describe is possible but the software to provide a virtual desktop capable of gaming isn’t going to be cheap

Comment: You will probably find it nor practical to implement and then tie computers to this big server. More flexible to have individual computers.

Comment: [Parsec](https://parsec.app/), [Moonlight](https://moonlight-stream.org/), [Sunshine](https://github.com/LizardByte/Sunshine), Steam Link. Also [Stadia](https://stadia.google.com/), [GeForce Now](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce-now/), [Xbox Cloud](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-game-pass/cloud-gaming).